# Javascript weather API text only

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, google-weather-api

I would like to use a text based weather API(Google API if exists) to show the current temperature of a given point(latitude,longitude). 
I don't want to show the map, only the value... In fact, What I want is to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var longitude=123456, 
         latitude=7890,
         url="???";
     $.getJSON(url,{long:longitude,lat:latitude},function(result){    
        $('div#weather').html("°F :"+_result);
     });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea ? if yes, share that with me please.
Thank you for reading

Comment: Hum, you just happened upon a good idea, thank you good sir :)

Answer (score 0):

[ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com) lists a number of APIs that deal with Weather information. You should investigate from the lsit if any of the APIs meets your requirements.

Weather Category APIs : http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/weather

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jQuery example : http://jsbin.com/isukam/1 with Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/).

Check [weather resource](http://metwit.com/weather-api/docs/resources/weather/) for more information.

Disclosure: I own this API.

Comment: Does not exist anymore